# XBee S2C fails communcation at some point

Tags: xbee

I have the following setup:

- A: 1 x Coordinator connected via USB dongle (sparkfun) to a Windows 10 IoT device - Serial communication
- B: 1 x Router connected to an Arduino Fio
- C: 1 x Router connected via USB dongle (sparkfun) to Windows 10 to XCTU

All above are API mode 1.

My scenario is as follows:

I send at each 5 seconds a 6 byte message from A to B and C.
B is instructed to reply to that message with another one of the same size.

After some time, typically 40 - 50 minutes, A no longer receives messages from B.
Reads from Serial port are working (Transmit Status messages are received for each message Sent by A).
C receives messages as seen in XCTU.

If nothing changes A will never hear from B again.

However if (by some internal logic) B sends a message to A (other than the reply) or if C sends a 6 byte message (same as the one A sends to B and C) to B, suddenly A starts receiving messages from B.

Does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: You'll have to post some code.  I'd suspect a bug in the code for module B on the Arduino Fio.

Comment: Do you know if I can somehow see if something is actually sent over the air between 2 XBees?

Comment: If you see a Transmit Status of 0 at the sender, then your message went over the air and was acknowledged by the remote device.  You'd have to check your serial communications to confirm that you're addressing the correct node.  You'll need an 802.15.4 sniffer to monitor OTA data.  Or connect a logic probe to the serial lines of device B to confirm that the XBee outputs your data.  Or add debug code to device B so you can monitor its state and possibly figure out what's happening.

Comment: @tomlogic It is a great idea! I do have a logic analyzer. I succesfully connected the probes and I can read bytes going back and forth. Now I wait for the moment when communication blocks to debug it. Thanks again!!!

Comment: So it seems that XBee receives the data. I'll try to debug the logic in Arduino to understand what can cause it to stop responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the arduino library that we misused.
It only works in API Mode 2 and we have the module configured for API Mode 1.
(does anyone know why the library has not yet been updated to be used with API Mode 1?)

It was happening only after a while since we have an incremental counter in our message and at some point, that counter reached a value that contained a special character from API Mode 2 perspective.

From XCTU was always running since there was no incremental logic in there.

Many thanks to @tomlogic for his suggestion. Helped a lot!